# How to add new String in array Index

Tags: android

How to add new string in alert dialog array index?

Suppose array index contain A,B,C and I want to add D in array index separately what do I do?

Let's suppose via items is

```
A
B
C
```

I want to add D additionally

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

//Set its title
builder2.setTitle("Pick an item");

final String [] viaitems;
viaitems = myString.split("<");

builder2.setItems(viaitems, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    // Click listener
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), viaitems[item],  
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

});

AlertDialog alert = builder2.create();

//display dialog box
alert.show();
```

Comment: You can't, either make your array size large enough to support more elements or use ArrayList to dynamically add more elements at anytime

Comment: how?????????????????????????

Comment: ArrayList<String> list =  new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("someNewString");
list.add("some other String");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

You can use `ArrayList` Refer this [DOC about ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html)

```
ArrayList<String> string_list;
```

Initilize your like

```
 string_list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You can add items like

```
string_list.add("A"):
string_list.add("B"):
string_list.add("C"):
```

You can add separately using index

```
string_list.add(1,"D");
```

Comment: ok thnx tel me one more thing how i will highlight or change color of  neew string in list????

Comment: @user3456519 while setting string to textview set the color for that textview

Comment: how i will change help me

Comment: @user3456519 where your diplaying text post that code

Comment: @user3456519 Are you playing with me Accepting/Unaccepting answer

Comment: @user3456519 where you need to display the item? tell me clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your intentions is but if you want to create an array of let's say +5 size.

```
final String [] viaitems;
viaitems = myString.split("<");

final String [] addedStringArr = Arrays.copyOf(viaitems, viaitems.length+5);

//you can set up whatever values you want.

addedStringArr[viaitems.length] = "1st Extra item"; //and so on for rest 5.
```

ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html **copyOf** method